# How to match Maya Units to blender units

Tags: units, unreal-engine

So am trying to match my blender Grid I had in maya while in uni but am struggling to do so and thus it make it hard to work with the modular tool kit i had made in maya anyway i can match them up?[image]

here is what i used to have in maya, thought it might have been 10000 and 100 instead. either or i would like to match blender with this maya units

Comment: Without knowing what length each "unit" is in Maya, it's impossible to answer that question!

Comment: Maya's default is in centimeters, same as blender, unless you change that to other metric system

Comment: i know that it is in centimetres but the way you edit the units in maya is different to the way you do it in blender. all i remember is that the way it used to work was so that it matched unreals movement increments. so it would snap 5 by 5, 10 by 10 and so on. i guess the best way i can say is that one box should be 5by 5 unreal units